# Azure publish not working with vs2013 express

Tags: azure, express, visual-studio-2013, publish

I can't publish my application on azure from vs 2013 express. and I have also installed update 5 for visual studio and azure sdk 2.7.

**Installed control panel:**
[image]

**Publish on azure**
[image]
Please help me out!!

Comment: did you reboot your pc? and did you try to open VS in Admin mode?

Answer (score 1):

Current latest SDK version is 2.8.1, try to install from below link

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=699287&clcid=0x409
```

---

alternatively, you can deploy via continues deployment, see below tutorial

Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/